# Update.php does nothing

Tags: 8, updating

I'm trying to do a minor security upgrade to Drupal 8.1.7  When I load update.php it gives me a blank page (no errors).

I upgraded all of the software with the exception of the root .htaccess and robots.txt files.

I'm getting this error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING or '(' in /home/energy/public_html/index.php on line 11

The line causing the error is the following one.

```
use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;
```

Comment: I'm running PHP 5.2.9.  This is probably the problem as Drupal now requires 5.3.  It is very strange as the previous versions of Drupal 8 ran fine on PHP 5.2.9.

Comment: You should use PHP 7 as its much faster than 5.5.9 or any other 5.something version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Drupal 8 requires PHP 5.5.9](https://www.drupal.org/requirements). If you are using PHP 5.2.9, it doesn't recognize as valid a line like `use Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel;` since [namespaces were introduced in PHP 5.3](http://php.net/manual/it/language.namespaces.rationale.php).

If you were already running a stable release of Drupal 8 before, check you didn't change in someway the PHP version used from your site.